# Using Teradata Volatile tables in Cognos transformer

Tags: sql, teradata, business-intelligence, cognos, cognos-bi

A cognos query turns out be a heavy CPU consumer which I tuned using Volatile tables. 
I'd like to know from someone who is familiar with implementing Volatile tables in Teradata via Cognos whether this is easily do-able . I did something like that in the past using JI's or materialized table but in the given situation VT's are the only option 
Original Q is something like this :

```
sel 
Case statements,
Sum ( Fct.C1)
Sum ( FCt.C2)
Case when ( Dim.C3  in < value list of  3000+) then ______
```

each of these column is part o the cubes and these are written by "framework manager" component as ICD files that contain the SQL

What I want to do is manually modify these ICD's to stick in the VT creation code and but still keep the Column list SAME

```
Create VT1 as ( sel ...) 
Create Vt2 as ( sel ...) 

Select  <same column list > 
from VT1 Join Conditions VT2 Join others
```

How can this be implemented and what challenges need to be addressed.

Comment: I don't think you can really use volatile tables in Cognos, unless you use hand-written SQL, which I wouldn't advise.  You can more or less accomplish the same thing in Cognos though.  Instead of using IQDs, use a report as the source for your cube.  In the report, just use two separate queries, one for each select, and then join those two queries together

Comment: It has to be in the same session for VT to be used. Can I have a report that feeds a cube and inside that single report are 3 queries . 2 CT for VT 's and 1 Q that uses the 2 VT's

Comment: I'm saying use two queries in Cognos to replicate the volatile tables (get the exact same result set), and then join those two queries together.

Comment: No I need the VT to choose my PI and the redistribution is the benefit from the VT.So it has to be VT's

Comment: Oh, got it.  You may be able to do it using native sql in your FM query subjects, I've never tried that though.  You could also look into using a stored procedure.

Comment: SP wont work because that's prolly a new session. `native sql in your FM query subjects` Can you pl shine some light there .